# Need Help Implementing Pagination in React App Using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, pagination

I'm currently working on a React application where I'm using Redux for state management. I've encountered a challenge in implementing pagination for a list of items fetched from an API.

Here's a brief overview of what I've tried:

1. Successfully fetched the data from the API and stored it in Redux store.
2. Implemented basic rendering of the items on a single page.

However, I'm struggling to figure out the best approach to implement pagination using Redux. I want to display a certain number of items per page and provide navigation to view more items.

Could someone guide me through the steps or share a sample implementation of pagination using Redux in a React app? I've considered using libraries like react-redux-paginate but would prefer a custom implementation to better understand the underlying logic.

```js
// Reducer
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  itemsPerPage: 10,
  // Other relevant state variables
};

// Actions and action creators

// Redux store setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually pagination of the results is part of the API,

Then you just query endpoint giving current `offset` and per page `limit` and on the front end you just keep track of the `offset`.

If API does not provide this feature and instead returns ALL results (what a poor design) then you could load all the `items` and as you started in `initialState` keep track of the "frame" you display, your actions could be `nextPage`, `prevPage` that will manipulate the `currentPage` (-=1, +=1) and the selector would return the amount of items as required.

```
const pagination = createSlice({
name: 'pagination',
initialState,
reducers: {
  clear: () => initialState,
  nextPage: (state,action) => {
    state.currentPage += 1;
    // it could be secured for going over the available pages
  },
  prevPage: (state, action) => {
    if(state.currentPage - 1 > 0) {
      state.currentPage -= 1;
    } else {
      state.currentPage = 0;
    }
  },
  // possible actions setItemsPerPage, setCurrentPage etc.
}
});
```

I assume `pagination` as slice name

```
const paginationSelector = ({ pagination }) => {  
  const { items, currentPage, itemsPerPage } = pagination;  
  const start = currentPage * itemsPerPage;

  return items.slice(start, start + itemsPerPage); 
};
```

Somewhere in component

```
const list = useSelector(paginationSelector);
```